# Python: Run Script to Write Several Files at Once

Tags: python, xml, performance, beautifulsoup

New to programming. I wrote a Python code (with help from stackoverflow) to read XML files in a directory and use BeautifulSoup to copy the text for an element and write this to an output directory. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys

source_folder='/Python27/source_xml'

for article in os.listdir(source_folder):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(source_folder+'/'+article))

    #I think this strips any tags that are nested in the sample_tag
    clean_text=soup.sample_tag.get_text("  ",strip=True)

    #This grabs an ID which I used as the output file name
    article_id=soup.article_id.get_text("  ",strip=True)

    with open(article_id,"wb") as f:
        f.write(clean_text.encode("UTF-8"))
```

The problem is I needed this to run for 100,000 XML files. I started the program last night and to my estimate it took 15 hours to run. Is there a way to, instead of reading and writing one at a time, to maybe read/write 100 or 1000 at a time, for example?

Comment: Have you checked that the writing of the file is the slowest step? Is it not the parsing of the XML files with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I think the parsing is not the bottleneck and I say that because each XMl file is about 50 KB on average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiprocessing module is your friend. You can automatically scale the code accross all your cpu's with a [process pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool


source_folder='/Python27/source_xml'

def extract_text(article):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(source_folder+'/'+article))

    #I think this strips any tags that are nested in the sample_tag
    clean_text=soup.sample_tag.get_text("  ",strip=True)

    #This grabs an ID which I used as the output file name
    article_id=soup.article_id.get_text("  ",strip=True)

    with open(article_id,"wb") as f:
            f.write(clean_text.encode("UTF-8"))

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(extract_text, os.listdir(source_folder))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: pardon the question from a python beginner - Do I need to modify any parameters in this code or is it ok to run as is?

Comment: Assuming your example code worked, this should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I"ll try it out on the next run.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I hate the idea, you could use threads. The GIL in python is released on I/O operations so you could run a threadpool and just consume jobs.